# Makefile: How to change prefix of var?

Tags: makefile

I have project folder with src, obj and inc dirs.

I declare var with obj - OBJS

```
SDIR = src
ODIR = obj

# I change /src/*.c to /obj/*.o
_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c))
# I need to change /src/*.o to /obj/*.o
OBJS = $(??? $ODIR ??? $_OBJS ???)
```

Now in _OBJS - `./src/*.o`, How to change in OBJS `/src/` to `/obj/`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this (if I understand the question correctly):

```
SDIR = src
ODIR = obj

# I change /src/*.c to /obj/*.o
_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c))
# I need to change /src/*.o to /obj/*.o
_OBJS := $(subst $(SDIR), $(ODIR), $(_OBJS))

debug:
    @echo $(_OBJS)
```

Output/Test:

```
$ mkdir ./src/
$ touch ./src/a.c
$ touch ./src/b.c
$ touch ./src/c.c
$ ls ./src/
a.c  b.c  c.c
$ make debug
obj/a.o obj/b.o obj/c.o
```

Comment: Thanks, Its looks fine. I will try it

Comment: I have reused the `_OBJS` variable. You can assign to a new one if you like

Comment: `OBJS =  $(subst $(SDIR), $(ODIR), $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c)))` I combined.

Answer (score 1):

```
_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.c))
_OBJS := $(notdir $(_OBJS)) 
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJS))
```

But, I think, its bad way